# xcode tabbed application with loginViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am fairly new to xcode so apologies if I am asking bad questions. My issue is that I have created a tabbed application but would like a login screen to show before the tabs display. There a lots of posts about this and the consensus is that you need to get your tabBarController to present a view controller. This makes sense but for some reason my app is not displaying the login screen. I'm going to paste my appDelegate.m code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

Tks

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sleep(3);
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [loginViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [_tabBarController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `_tabBarController` to `self.tabBarController` and moving the `presentViewController` call to after `makeKeyAndVisible`...

Answer (score 1):

You should do the presentation from the controller in the first tab (assuming that's the controller you want to show after the login screen is dismissed). Do the presentation from the viewDidAppear method with the animated argument set to NO.